# Reputation graph displaying half days

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

When you select the "graph" display option on your reputation tab you get a graph that has half a bar on either end of said graph.

This originates from the URL that is being used for the "Graph" button.
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/361484/luuklag?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2019-11-27%2011:52:00Z` Where a time is included in the start date.

However the page seems not to respond to changing these parameters. It will always produce below screen.

[image]

If I do a manual selection, by dragging in the lower bar I get some nice white-space for future dates.

[image]

That the left side of the graph produces half a day doesn't bother me too much, but seeing today's day as half a day does. It would be better to have tomorrow as half a day of white-space.

Comment: You can zoom in at the millisecond level to learn what your rep was at that moment ...

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign] I'd think

Comment: I'd consider that status-by-flawed-design then @Mast

Comment: Absolutely. What I'm really saying is this may be a [tag:feature-request] instead.